# How to print an integer to transcript

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I've tried the code

```
|myNum|
myNum := SmallInteger new: 0.
Transcript show: (myNum printString).
```

, but Pharo crashes upon running this code.

Comment: What's interesting in your example is that you found a missing protection in the VM. We can't protect against everything, but we should better protect against such simple flaw.

Comment: Bug is fixed in Spur, the next-generation VM that Eliot is currently writing: Cog-eem.127

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create a SmallInteger using `new:`. You already have the number you want to print. It's already a SmallInteger. Just use it like such:

```
Transcript show: 0 printString
```

Answer (score 4):

"SmallInteger new: 0" is not necessary since 0 is already a SmallInteger.

Besides, the #show: message of the Transcript object already sends #asString to its parameter, therefore it can receive any object.

So the correct code would be:

```
Transcript show: 0
```

Comment: I think not all Smalltalk dialects send #asString to the parameter to #show: , so sending #asString doesn't hurt.